# Mapping Django urls and views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

Guys i am new to Django but i am bit clued up on a few things. I need help with urls. So in my models.py i defined category, subcategory and product models and all these models fields have got a slugfield. I have also managed to define the index page url and its working but after the index page i want when the user clicks the category link he will be able to see subcategories that are under categories,  and when the user click on subcategories he will able to see products in the subcategory. So for example i would love to create an url like www.127.0000/electronics , **electronics** is the **category** and under electronics the user will be able to see **subcategories** like *TV's , Microwaves*...when the user click on TV's link the url will be www.127.0000/electronics/tvs and at this page the user will see the products. This is my models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug= models.SlugField(max_length= 100, unique= True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name= 'category'
        verbose_name_plural= 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SubCategory (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    slug = models.SlugField (max_length= 200, unique= True)
    category= models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name= "SubCategory"
        verbose_name_plural= 'SubCategories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10 , decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=20, blank= True)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name= 'product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'products'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and this is my app urls

```
urlpatterns= [
    path('', views.index, name='Index'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.category, name= 'Categories' )
```

views.py file

```
def index (request):
    """"Defines homepage"""
    return render (request, 'index.html')

def category (request, category_slug):
     """Defines categories slug"""
    categories= get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    context= {'categories': categories}
    return render (request, 'category.html', context}
```

this is my category html gile

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<p>
    <ul>
    {% for category in categories %}
    <li> {{category}} </li>
    {% empty %}
    <li> No Category has been added yet</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</p>

{% endblock content %}
```

Could you please guide in the right direction so that when i click on www.127.0000/clothes i see the subcategories in clothes and the i click on and subcategories the url will change to maybe 127.000/clothes/men clothes and display the products in men clothes subcategory.

Comment: `categories` is a *single* `Category`, not multiple ones. So you should not use a `{% for ... %}` loop.

Comment: the reason i used the {% for %} loop was to show a list of  individual categories stored in the query set.  So what do you suggest i use instead of the for loop in my template